# WooCommerce need to call an external API when new user created and new order placed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to trigger custom API calls in the WooCommerce website in the below scenarios

1. When new customer created
2. when new order placed
3. when payment completed

I want to call 3 different api's when these actions are performed, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is for payment hook

```
3. add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
```

this is for new order

```
2. add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'create_invoice_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
```

For number 1 you should make custom hook.

Comment: Thank you @Ariful, I have an issue while implementing the "woocommerce_new_order"  hook, it doesn't work, after submitting the form its redirecting to payment page.
 I want some action to be done before payment.

Comment: check if any action is available before payment